# Why is the Ubuntu Control Panel so limited?

Tags: settings

I love the newest version of Ubuntu except for one thing: the control panel. It is is limited. Is there a way to get another program to access some of these "locked" settings? Thank you everyone for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a GNOME 3 change, and there is a utility named `gnome-tweak-tool` or "Advanced Settings" that you can [install](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gnome-tweak-tool/) from the Ubuntu repositories.

You can also install [ubuntu-tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) to access some unity configurations and other settings. Also you can install the dconf-editor to edit some hidden options of gnome and unity but it is only recommended if you know what are you doing:

```
sudo-apt-get install dconf-tools
```

and then in the alt+f2 menu or in a terminal type

```
dconf-editor
```